# Serving content from django

Tags: python, angularjs, django, amazon-web-services, content-management-system

I have a platform with about 30,000 pages. I would like to add content for each page (manually).

I wondered what is the best way to do that?

I am using django + angular and I dont use django templats. 
It feels like adding text params to the django model is not the best idea since it will make my DB too heavy.

I looked into django-cms but it seems that it based on django templates.

Comment: Is it impossible to use Angular for users, and Django templates for admin page?

Comment: @Chiefir yes it is possible.

Comment: so why dont you use that? I think that will be the easiest way.

Comment: @Chiefir because then all the content will be on my DB and each page will need to pull a lot of content from the DB, I believe there is a more 'elegant' way to do it.

Comment: Why do u think so? Django admin is highly optimised, and uses pagination. So even if u have a lot of data in some model - it will get only paginated amount of that data. More to that you can customize your admin page anyhow you want.

Comment: @Chiefir I am not talking about the admin, I am talking about the end user, when the page will load the pull from the DB for that page will be very heavy and it will 'cost' a lot.

Comment: you want to have something like cms, but available to all your users, not only admins?

Comment: @Chiefir I am the only one who enter the content. All the users see the content.

Comment: So I still does not understand what is wrong  to use Django as admin and Angular as front end. Querying data from db with Angular has nothing with adding data in Django admin.

Comment: @Chiefir the thing is that I don't want to flood my DB with so much content which will make it heavy and slow.

Comment: You want to have a lot of content on your site, you are afraid it to be slow? But that is not a problem of Django, but of your database server and database optimisation.

Comment: @Chiefir my question is where should I store the content, in the main DB or should I create an alternative db for content? will strong content on my main DB is a good practice?